# How can I create a limit that something can happen in a specific time period

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a mod for minecraft and it uses an api. The rule with the api is you can not make more than 120 requests in 1 minute or your api will be banned. I was wondering what I can do to make it so that every time you reach 110 requests in 50 seconds it stops everything and when that minute is over, it continues again. Thanks. Sorry if you don't understand. If you don't I can explain better.

Comment: What about a `Thread` that counts or sleeps or does something like that?

Comment: That might work. Do you think you could give me an example?

Comment: If you show me some code in which you plan to count requests and stop a time, then maybe…
Best would be you post it here, so other people may come up with an example!

Comment: every time that the event is triggered, is it possible to add up a number until it gets to 110? in a specific time period

Comment: You could store the current system time when the event gets triggered first and start incrementing the counter variable. Then every time the event gets triggered and the counter is not 0, you check the difference between current time and stored start time.

Comment: Are you sure that the API clock get's reset every 60 seconds? Generally, from what I have seen of API's it's more of a rolling window.

Comment: Just to check: Is it 120 requests *per client* or 120 requests *per developer ID?* The difference here is important. If you make your mod, distribute it to 120 people, and each make 1 api request in the same 60 second window: are you fine...or not fine?